# How to use my own internal JSON data with Zingchart?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, visualization, zingchart

[image: This the drill down example from zing chart]

My problems here is that they are loading the data from an external resource which return JSON, instead of this I want to know how can we give our own internal JSON data which is there in a variable as a URL parameter

Comment: You cannot pass a queryParam as a variable. If you want to pass a variable just the `node_click` or `plot_click` api and access and JavaScript information inside that event listener -> https://www.zingchart.com/docs/api/events#node_click